create a simple website in odoo without any default views
i try to create a simple website for displaying some informations. I do not need records only a button to create a sequence number.
I tried many things but it always shows me the default odoo page with the new button, search function and so on. I don't know what i have to do to create a simple website.
Here my model and views:
Model:
debit_card.py
from odoo import fields, models

class DebitCard(models.TransientModel):
_name="debit.card"
_desctiption="Heinzmann debit card"

manifest.py
{
'category':'Uncategorized',
'version':'0.1',
'depends':['base'],
'data':[
    'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    'views/debit_card_actions.xml',
    'views/debit_card_menu_items.xml',
    'views/debit_card_view.xml'
]

}
Views:
debit_card_view.xml:
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="debit_card_form_view">
        <field name="name">debit.card.form.view</field>
        <field name="model">debit_card</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="test" id="test">
            <sheet>
                <div>
                    Hello World!
                </div>
            </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

debit_card_menu_items.xml:
<menuitem id="debit_card_root_menu" name="Kundenkarte"/>
    <menuitem id="debit_card_sub_root_menu" name="Übersicht" parent="debit_card_root_menu"/>
    <menuitem id="debit_card_sub_sub_root_menu" action="debit_card_action" name="Übersicht" parent="debit_card_sub_root_menu"/>

debit_card_actions.xml:
<record id="debit_card_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Kundenkarte</field>
        <field name="res_model">debit_card</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

Can anyone help me?

U shouldnt use  but install the Website App and then create ur custom module containing an inherited template such as: 

If your purpose is to create your own template lavout, u could create your own template, using this official tuto: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/howtos/website_themes/theming.html#theme-module

To keep it as easy as possible, you can just install the Website App and then create your custom module containing such template, that inherits the default "web.layout":
 <template id="my_web_layout" name="My WebLayout" inherit_id="web.layout">
<!-- create your custom xml weblayout by using xpath-replacements -->

Oherwise, if your purpose is to create your very own full-fledged website template lavout, you can achieve it using this official tutorial: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/howtos/website_themes/theming.html#theme-module.

Ok. I try to create my own layout by the tutorial link. Thanks.

it woud be easier to get familiar with part.1 of the answer if you are a beginner. Please consider up-voting if my answers have helped you...

Ok. Is the way over controllers a alternative too? Because i don´t know how to use xpath in relation with templates.

You just need controller as interface between your template(view) and the model that enables to store your data in the database

You should get familiar with xpath, because it would be a waste of time to redefine a web.layout from scratch...
